# Inherit sass modifier in extending classes

Tags: css, sass

I have a base class for all buttons that looks like

```scss
.btn {
    height: var(--btn-height-base);
    padding: 0 10px;

    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

Button designs extend this class like this:

```scss
.btn-primary {
    @extend .btn;
    background: var(--color-brand);
    color: var(--txt-white);

    &:active,
    &:hover {
        background: var(--color-brand-active);
        color: var(--txt-white);
    }
}
```

I want to add a modifier to all designs called `--icon` that applies `gap: 6px;`. It would then be used like `btn-primary--icon` or `btn-border--icon`. Is this possible without repeating this modifier in all my button designs? I have tried adding

```scss
&--icon {
    @extend .btn;
    gap: 6px;
}
```

to my `.btn` class, but that only seems to apply to `.btn--icon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible, as explained [in the docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend/):

> Extends are resolved after the rest of your stylesheet is compiled. In particular, it happens after [parent selectors](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector/) are resolved. This means that if you `@extend .error`, it won’t affect the inner selector in `.error { &__icon { ... } }`. It also means that [parent selectors in SassScript](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector/#in-sassscript) can’t see the results of extend.